# Equivalent of flatten method in Scala 2.11 to handle nested futures

Tags: scala

In scala 2.12 I can write the following code

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val x = Future(Future(10))
val y = x.flatten
```

However, scala 2.11 does not provide a flatten method. Any idea how can I achieve the same result in scala 2.11

edit: Can the cats library help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
val y = x.flatMap(identity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Cats, but Scalaz has method `join` for that:

```
val y = x.join
```

Moreover, this method works for all Monads.